# desktop search algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Anybody has idea on how desktop search algorithm is implemented. Any starting point would be helpful.

Comment: What is a desktop search algorithm?

Comment: I am thinking of scanning all the files on a server , read the contents of all the text files to start with and allow customer to search any keyword and show him what file/files has this keyword.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for.. http://www.seobythesea.com/?p=519

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified much in your question, but I guess this white paper

> [Everything you don't know about desktop search](http://www.isys-search.com/resources/whitepapers/desktop.pdf)

should give you a head-start.